# Reflection - Navigate a non-generic method from a generic type definition to a concrete one

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Let's say I have a class as follow:

```
    class A<T>
    {
        public void Method()
        {
        }
    }
```

So the class is generic but its methods aren't.

I can find the method, say:

```
var m = typeof(A<int>).GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetMethod("Method");
```

Now I would like to navigate from this 'm' (which is really `A<T>.Method`) to a concrete type, e.g. `A<int>.Method`.

I would like to do that in a general way, i.e. I don't want to use method name since I might have cases with overloaded number of parameters.

Is there a way to do that or do I have to load the methods with the same names and compare parameters?

Comment: Why are you using `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` at all? Just use `typeof(A<int>).GetMethod("Method")`

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to map a generic (i.e. type definition) type and its method and then, when the concrete type is known, match a method.  The thing is, the code base is already in a paradigm of 'per method', so I'm centered on a method.

Comment: It's really unclear what your *actual* inputs and outputs are. In your sample code, you've got `A<int>` hard-coded - so there's no point in going via `GetGenericTypeDefinition`. It would really help if you'd take another stab at explaining what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [MakeGenericType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) method, like this:

```
m.DeclaringType.MakeGenericType(typeof(int))
```

and then probably `GetMethod` again if you really want to go this way:

```
m.DeclaringType.MakeGenericType(typeof(int)).GetMethod("Method");
```

However, consider Jon Skeet's comment for simpler solution.

Comment: This solution returns me a type, not a MethodInfo though.

Comment: @Vincent-PhilippeLauzon yes, the `GetMethod` will give you the `MethodInfo` type. I put it together for you, but I'm not sure what was so hard about this... ;)